# Tax on transfer of funds to USA

Tags: income-tax, money-transfer

I m Indian citizen, living in a African country. How much tax liability will be there on transfer of funds to USA from this African country? Moving to USA is due to employment.

Comment: There is no tax to move your own money from one place to another.

Comment: @user102008 why don't you put it as an answer?

Comment: Knowing the source country might be important. I seem to remember that some countries have put limits on how much money can be moved out, how quickly, in order to try to encourage local reinvestment and/or to keep companies from fleeing the country during an upheaval. I don't know if or where any of those policies are currently in effect, but I'd suggest researching that before concluding that there's no tax on either end of the transaction.

Comment: what African country?

Answer (score 2):

There is no tax to move your own money from one place to another.

Comment: Perhaps more accurate to say that the US does not tax it.  (But let's not give them ideas.)  Do we know enough about the African country in question to know whether it's taxed on their end?